# Scrolling background sides appearance of a line

Tags: java, android, background, libgdx, screen

in my game (using libgdx) i use a scrolling background the scrolling Background it's work good for some backgrounds like this :

[Good one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRwWF.jpg)

but when i draw my own background using inkscape or photoshope if i use a line in the sides of the background or something like shadow the probelm of a black line appear , except if i use a picture with one color and drawing in the middle . that's mean the problem is from the picture but why in the others background it's work good (There is no problem in the code and measurements)???

[Appearance of a line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbpIC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If code would be attached, would be great. But looks like, when drawing sprite, need draw one pixel less at the beginning, or draw one pixel more end in the end of sprite.